# Declaring object type as NSManagedObject or class name

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

In Core Data, if I have a Person entity is there any difference between:

```
NSManagedObject *aPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

or

```
Person *aPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

Should aPerson be of type Person or NSManagedObject?  Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare it as aPerson class.  That way the complier know the exact class type.